# How to Create an HTML Input for US Phone Numbers with Automatic '+1' Prefix and Digits-Only Input?

Tags: html, jquery

I want to create an HTML input field for US phone numbers that automatically formats the input. The desired format is "+1 xxx-xxx-xxxx". The input field should allow users to type digits only and should automatically add "+1" at the start of the input field.

```
<input type="text" name="phone-number" maxlength="15">

$("input[name='phone-number']").on("input", function(){
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "+1 $1-$2-$3"));
});
```

I've tried using the on-input event to add "+1" at the beginning, but it keeps adding "1" each time a number or backspace is pressed. I need help with a JavaScript or jQuery solution to achieve this desired behavior without adding "1" repeatedly.

Once formatting the input value and reaching the max length of 15, pressing backspace will produce 1 at the beginning of the input.

`.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "+1 $1-$2-$3")` or `.replace(/\D/g, '')` works fine individually alone and doesn't produce the same issues but once combined they produce some issues like unable to use backspace and pressing backspace will add "1"

How do I fix this?

Comment: what's the issue with `$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "+1 $1-$2-$3"));` only?

Answer (score 0):

To format while typing in textbox:

```js
$("input[name='phone-number']").on("input", function (event) {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            if (event.key == 'Backspace' && txt.endsWith('-')) {
                txt = txt.slice(0, - 1);
            }
            txt = txt.replace(/\+1/, '').replace(/\D/g, '',);
            var n = txt.length;
            switch (true) {
                case (n <= 3):
                    break;
                case (n > 3 && n <= 6):
                    txt = txt.substring(0, 3) + '-' + txt.substring(3, 6);
                    break;
                case (n > 6):
                    txt = txt.substring(0, 3) + '-' + txt.substring(3, 6) + '-' + txt.substring(6);
            }
            $(this).val('+1 ' + txt);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input type="text" name="phone-number" maxlength="15" />
```